# How can I tidy my relative references using CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm quite new to C++ and trying to get to grips with CMake and referencing files elsewhere in the project. My references within my test file currently looks like this:

```
#include "catch.hpp"
#include "../../src/containers/containers.h"
```

How can I tidy this up using CMake to have the following?

```
#include "catch.hpp"
#include "src/containers/containers.h"
```

My folder structure is as follows:

```
Project
├── lib
│   └── Catch2
│       └── catch.hpp
├── src
│   ├── containers
│   │    ├── containers.cpp
│   │    └── containers.h
│   └── CMakeLists.cpp
├── tests
│   ├── bin
│   ├── containers
│   │    └── test_containers.html
│   ├── CMakeLists.cpp
│   └── tests_main.cpp
├── CMakeLists.cpp
└── main.cpp
```

And my current CMakeLists.txt in `./tests/` is as follows:

```
set(CATCH_INCLUDE_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/Catch2")

add_library(Catch INTERFACE)

target_include_directories(Catch INTERFACE ${CATCH_INCLUDE_DIR})

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/tests/bin)

add_executable(test_containers tests_main.cpp containers/test_containers.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test_containers Catch containers)
add_test(NAME test_containers COMMAND test_containers)

enable_testing()
```

I include the following directories in my base CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(tests)
```

And in src, I make `containers` a library:

```
add_library(containers STATIC
            containers/containers.cpp
            containers/containers.h)
```

Comment: Are you currently unable to use ```#include "catch.hpp"
#include "containers.h"``` ?

Comment: I figured out that `#include catch.hpp` works like 20 seconds after posting this, but not for containers for some reason

Comment: It looks to me like you're "including" ```catch.hpp```'s base directory in ```CMakeLists.txt```, but you're never doing the same for ```containers.h```.

Comment: okay, I swear I tried this before posting but adding `target_include_directories(containers PUBLIC "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src")` gets me exactly what I want

Comment: Happens all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the line `target_include_directories(containers PUBLIC "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src")` solved the issue and allowed my references to be reduced as desired.

Comment: you should prefer to use "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}"

Comment: care to explain why?

Comment: even better once you'll add install rules: `PUBLIC $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}>` otherwise CMake can complain about adding absolute local path to install artifact

Comment: CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR is top level source dir and you can't always know it especially if you are integrated into a super project or you decide to change project layout  while CURRENT is relative to the current CMakeLists.txt being processed
ref: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR.html
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR.html

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the difference, I just wasn't clear on the reason that one should prefer CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR. In this instance, the project won't be integrated into a wider program, so I couldn't imagine why it would be of use, however your point is a good one so I will likely make the change just to get into the habit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

following my comments, supposing you want to use `#include "containers.h"`

```
target_include_directories(containers
  PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/containers>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include/containers>)

set_target_properties(containers PROPERTIES
  PUBLIC_HEADER containers/containers.h)

# Install
include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS containers
  EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}Targets
  PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/containers
  # ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
  # LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
  # RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
  )
```

ref:

- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html
- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR.html
- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GNUInstallDirs.html
- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#targets